# Is the charge present only on the outer surface of a spherical conducting sphere or on both inner and outer surfaces?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, conductors

Recently I was taught that in a conductor charge resides only on the surface of the conductor and the net charge inside a conductor is zero and so is the net electric field.

But what if the conductor had two surfaces like in a spherical conducting shell?

Suppose we provide a charge 'Q' to a spherical conducting shell. Is the charge on the inner surface of the shell equal to zero or is the charge divided equally among the two surfaces(Q/2 on the outer surface and Q/2 on the inner surface)? I'm in a dilemma.

NOTE: Initially There is no charge inside the cavity of the shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there are charges in the interior of the conducting shell, since the electric field in a conductor must be zero at steady state, [Gauss' law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law#Integral_form) requires that there be no charge on the inner surface of the conductor. All of the charge will reside on the outer surface.

Answer (score 1):

Charges repel one another and will get as far apart as they can.  Since the shell is a conductor, nothing is stopping them from moving to the outer surface which is as far apart as they can get from one another.